# Adding months to a date in access based on a number in another field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database of documents with a "last reviewed" date field, another field has a number which states how many months until this document expires (6, 12, 18, 24)
I would like to display all the document which expire each month based on the review dates X the months till expire.

for example 
if 3 documents have a date of 28/03/2017 and a 6 month review i would like a box on a menu which states 3 documents need to be reviewed in September.

any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: Start by using the DateAdd function to add "m" months, to get your expiry date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the future month to check, then calculate the expire date for the documents, and finally compare these.

Then you can use *DCount* in an expression for your textbox counting the documents:

```
=DCount("*","YourTable","DateDiff('m',DateAdd('m'," & [YourMonthsForwardTextbox] & ", Date()),DateAdd('m',[Expires],[Last Reviewed]))=0")
```